# Lyx preamble definecolor error

Tags: lyx, preamble

I have a lot of custom commands in my preamble, and I am using these setting for all my new and old documents. Lately I added a command to change the default green color by adding the following command:

```
\definecolor{green}{RGB}{0, 180, 0}
```

The problem is that whenever one of my documents *doesn't have any text colored* I get the following error:

[image: The error I get]

**Important note:** It only happens whenever there is no text colored in the document.

Is there any way to make the **definecolor** command execute only if there is any coloring in my document? Or any other suggestions will be appreciated.

**Edit:** More information that might help:
I have the following packages at the beginning of the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{ fancyhdr }
\usepackage{ pifont }
\usepackage{ graphicx }
```

Comment: Do you invoke `\usepackage{xcolor}` somewhere in your preamble?

Comment: @NBur Edited the post for more information.

Comment: no dsfont doesn't do it, and your error message clearly says that you are missing a color package. So load it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Last time I tried to add `xcolor` I got error that said that this package is already loaded, any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se ! If you post a minimal working example .lyx file, I will provide a solution. For more information, please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. If anyone else wants to beat me to it, you just need to use the "Provides" layout tag in order to always load xcolor instead of having LyX do it.

Comment: @h3110w0r1d did you figure out a solution? If so, can you post an answer?

Comment: Adding xcolor mostly helped